# What should I import to be able to use the following code correctly?

Tags: java, android

Hi Im trying to read an Excel file into my android application. I tried using this code:

```
try {
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row;
    HSSFCell cell;

    int rows; // No of rows
    rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    int cols = 0; // No of columns
    int tmp = 0;

    // This trick ensures that we get the data properly even if it doesn't start from first few rows
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 || i < rows; i++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if(row != null) {
            tmp = sheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            if(tmp > cols) cols = tmp;
        }
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if(row != null) {
            for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                cell = row.getCell((short)c);
                if(cell != null) {
                    // Your code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch(Exception ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was wondering if I should import anything or any library?

Comment: What happens? Are you getting errors?

Comment: You don't really need to wonder; the IDE/compiler will tell you what it doesn't understand.

Comment: Where did you find this code? I assume it's on some web page explaining how to use the library X. How could X not be mentioned on this web page? Anyway, X is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), as you would have found yourself by googling for POIFSFileSystem for example.

Comment: This sounds like a library to read Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse as your IDE (I assume you are since this is Android related) you can press ctrl + shift + O and it will automatically import anything you need, assuming you have the libraries included in your build path. However, it sounds like you don't have the Apache POI libraries. First you need to [download](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.8) the libraries. After they are downloaded you need to add them to your build path using the following method: (Again assuming that you are using Eclipse as your IDE)

1. Right click your project in the project explorer.
2. Choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path
3. Choose the library tab.
4. Click "Add JARs..."
5. Find and select the JAR file that you just downloaded. (You might need to copy the JAR into your project so that you are able to select it)

Alternatively, you can add the library to one of your project folders (typically a "lib" folder), right click it in Eclipse and select "Add to Build Path".

It should now be added to your build path. Again try hitting ctrl + shift + O and the necessary imports will be made for you.

Comment: Maybe.  If it has knowledge of it.  Code for using some random library won't be something Eclipse can help you with, unless Eclipse has been pointed at an installation of that library.

Comment: I did import everything using the shortcut but it still askes me to create all those classes:POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row;
    HSSFCell cell;    Sorry im a new user of android

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the libraries downloaded. Check my updated answer.